# Change the original IP for Visitor Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, cloudflare

I am using **CloudFlare**  which change the original ip for visitors, I need to return the original IP, I am using **Zend framework**.

I need to replace  `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`  **With**    `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']`

AND

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue on Ubuntu Follow the below Instructions

## make sure you're root

```
sudo -i
wget https://www.cloudflare.com/static/misc/mod_cloudflare/mod_cloudflare.c
apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev # or apache2-threaded-dev
apxs2 -ci mod_cloudflare.c
tee /etc/apache2/mods-available/cloudflare.load <<EOF
LoadModule cloudflare_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cloudflare.so
EOF
tee /etc/apache2/mods-available/cloudflare.conf <<EOF
CloudFlareRemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
CloudFlareRemoteIPTrustedProxy 10.0.0.0/8
EOF
a2enmod cloudflare
service apache2 reload
```